# The effect of using mid=first+(last-first)/2 instead of (first+last)/2

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Why do people use mid=first+(last-first)/2 instead of (first+last)/2,in case of binary search)
Is there a difference between the two. If there is then please tell as I can't understand the difference.

Comment: sorry man,just changed the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `mid = (first + last) / 2` then there is a chance of overflow when first or last is `MAX`, i.e. when first or last is the maximum or range, adding one more number to it will overflow.

So we use `mid = first + (last-first) / 2`, as this will not overflow even when first or last is the max of range.

Also, as in competitive programming test cases are made which will test your code to extreme scenarios, it is very much possible that one of the test case has these maximum of range number. So it advisable to use `mid  = first + (last-first)/2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Java and C++ for instance the latter (`(hi + lo) / 2`) might throw an exception, if hi + lo becomes too large. In Python and JavaScript, it would probably be okay.

It seems there are more info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571359/why-we-write-lohi-lo-2-in-binary-search).

#### Reference

[Calculating mid in binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735259/calculating-mid-in-binary-search)

Answer (score 1):

both will give the same result if `first+last < Maximum_value_for_a_variable`.
so it is much safer using `mid=first+(last-first)/2` to avoid overflow.
let's assume first, last and mid are int variables.

```
int mid; 
int first = 50010;
int last = 2147483275;
//Maximum value for a variable of type int is 2147483647
(first+last)/2 //-1073717005 overflow because first+last > integer maximum value
first+(last-first)/2 //1073766642 no overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of the programming languages, there's a limit for a data type. So, if we use `(first+last)/2` then adding first and last might exceed that given limit and it will produce a run time error.

To avoid this, it is advised to use `first + (last-first)/2`. As in extreme scenarios also, it will not cross the limit of its data type.